# Error " avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4" local variable cannot be declared in this scope

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass all avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4 on the `outputdisp` method. I don't know how, as at the same time on the second method `avrg` I'm also receiving from another method, but I need to give it out as well.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
 {
 double totalspendf = 0, totalspendc = 0, totalspendcr = 0, totalspendo = 0, avg1=0, avg2=0, avg3=0, avg4=0;
 dailyspend(ref totalspendf, ref totalspendc, ref totalspendcr, ref totalspendo);
 avrg(totalspendf, totalspendc, totalspendcr, totalspendo, avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4);
 outputdisp(totalspendc, totalspendf, totalspendcr, totalspendo, avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4);
 Console.ReadLine();
 }
 }

 static void dailyspend(ref double totalspendf, ref double totalspendc, ref double totalspendcr, ref double totalspendo)
 { int days;
 double spendf = 0, spendc = 0, spendcr = 0, spendo = 0;
 for (days = 1; days <= 2; days++)
 {
 Console.WriteLine("");
 do
 {
 Console.Write("Food : ");
 spendf = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 } while (spendf < 0);
 do
 {
 Console.Write("Clothing : ");
 spendc = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 } while (spendc < 0);
 do
 {
 Console.Write("College related : ");
 spendcr = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 } while (spendcr < 0);
 do
 {
 Console.Write("Outside: ");
 spendo = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 } while (spendo < 0);

 Console.WriteLine("");
 totalspendf += spendf;
 totalspendc += spendc;
 totalspendcr += spendcr;
 totalspendo += spendo;
 }
 }

 public static double avrg(double totalspendf, double totalspendc, double totalspendcr, double totalspendo, double avg1, double avg2, double avg3, double avg4)
 {
 double avg, avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4;

 avg1 = totalspendc / 2;
 avg2 = totalspendcr / 2;
 avg3 = totalspendf / 2;
 avg4 = totalspendo / 2;
 avg = (totalspendc + totalspendcr + totalspendf + totalspendo) / 2;

 return avg;

}

static void outputdisp(double totalspendc, double totalspendf,double totalspendcr,double totalspendo,double avg1, double avg2, double avg3,double avg4)
{ double avg;
Console.WriteLine("Categories               Total            Average    ");
Console.WriteLine("Clothes                  " + totalspendc.ToString("C") + "           " + avg1.ToString("C"));
Console.WriteLine("Food                     " + totalspendf.ToString("C") + "           " + avg3.ToString("C"));
Console.WriteLine("College related          " + totalspendcr.ToString("C")+ "           " + avg2.ToString("C"));
Console.WriteLine("Outside                  " + totalspendo.ToString("C") + "           " + avg4.ToString("C"));
Console.WriteLine("");
avg = avrg(totalspendf, totalspendc, totalspendcr, totalspendo);
Console.WriteLine("Average spend for this week : " + avg.ToString("C"));

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function "avrg" already has arguments with the same names i.e.

> avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4.

Either you eliminate those arguments or change name of variables.

I have updated your code a bit. Hope this will work for you -

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double totalspendf = 0, totalspendc = 0, totalspendcr = 0, totalspendo = 0, avg1 = 0, avg2 = 0, avg3 = 0, avg4 = 0;
        dailyspend(ref totalspendf, ref totalspendc, ref totalspendcr, ref totalspendo);
        avrg(totalspendf, totalspendc, totalspendcr, totalspendo, ref avg1, ref avg2, ref avg3, ref avg4);
        outputdisp(totalspendc, totalspendf, totalspendcr, totalspendo, avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void dailyspend(ref double totalspendf, ref double totalspendc, ref double totalspendcr, ref double totalspendo)
    {
        int days;
        double spendf = 0, spendc = 0, spendcr = 0, spendo = 0;
        for (days = 1; days <= 2; days++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Food : ");
                spendf = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            } while (spendf < 0);
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Clothing : ");
                spendc = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            } while (spendc < 0);
            do
            {
                Console.Write("College related : ");
                spendcr = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            } while (spendcr < 0);
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Outside: ");
                spendo = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            } while (spendo < 0);

            Console.WriteLine("");
            totalspendf += spendf;
            totalspendc += spendc;
            totalspendcr += spendcr;
            totalspendo += spendo;
        }
    }

    public static double avrg(double totalspendf, double totalspendc, double totalspendcr, double totalspendo, ref double avg1,ref double avg2,ref double avg3,ref double avg4)
    {
        double avg;

        avg1 = totalspendc / 2;
        avg2 = totalspendcr / 2;
        avg3 = totalspendf / 2;
        avg4 = totalspendo / 2;
        avg = (totalspendc + totalspendcr + totalspendf + totalspendo) / 2;

        return avg;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already declared avg, avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4 in the function, that's why it is throwing error.
delete the below statement or change the variable names

```
 double avg, avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4;
```

your problem will be solved